# Why are my Dependencies Not Injected?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I have a simple MVC5 App. I want to inject a repository in to one of my Controllers.

The Controller looks like this ...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    IToDoRepository repo;

    public HomeController(IToDoRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    // Methods ...
}
```

My Repository looks like this...

```
public class ToDoRepository : IToDoRepository
{
    ToDoListData data;

    public ToDoRepository(ToDoListData dataSource)
    {
        this.data = dataSource;
    }

    // Blah...
}
```

And `ToDoListData` is just a dummy data source defined like this ...

```
public class ToDoListData : List<ToDoItem>
{
    public ToDoListData()
    {
        Add(new ToDoItem { Id = 1, Title = "Do Shopping" });
        Add(new ToDoItem { Id = 2, Title = "Feed Dogs", Complete = true });
        Add(new ToDoItem { Id = 3, Title = "Pay Gas Bill" });
    }
}
```

Using nuget, I've added the Unity.Mvc5 package. The total list of packages installed in the project is...

```
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity" version="3.0.1304.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity.Mvc5" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity.WebAPI" version="5.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I updated Global.asax to call `UnityConfig.RegisterComponents()` and modified that method to look like this ...

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IToDoRepository, ToDoRepository>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<ToDoListData, ToDoListData>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
            new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

    }
}
```

Now, I'm relatively new to this, but what I've read suggests (or at least my addled brain seems to think it suggests) that this should run.

However.

Firing up the site returns..

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Can anyone suggest what I might have missed?

Comment: Is `ToDoListData` an abstract class? interface?

Comment: Do `ToDoRepository` and `ToDoListData` have accessible parameterless constructors?

Comment: I've updated the Q to include the definition of `ToDoListData`. The `ToDoListRepository` doesn't have a parameterless constructor. But I thought that as I've defined the type of the parameter in UnityConfig.cs it should get properly resolved.

Comment: <package id="Unity" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity.Mvc" version="3.5.1404.0" targetFramework="net45" /> this is one of  my project configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I think below is the right way to overwrite a dependency resolver.

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

I suggest you use mvc unity bootstrapper instead of unity package from nuget. Bootsrapper comes with basic set up.

Comment: Is that 'as well as' or 'instead of' the Unity.Mvc5 package?

Comment: i think it could this one...Install-Package Unity.Mvc5 I have used it quite a while back so dont really remember

Comment: That's the one I AM using. Sorry, I misread your previous message; I thought you were saying IU _shouldn't_ use that package.

Comment: I've updated the question to include details of _all_ of the installed nuget packages and their versions.

Comment: SetResolver isn't an available method. The line `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);` isn't something I added; it is included as part of the nuget installation.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. I don't see ToDoList, but assume it is parameterless, so that would not be the issue. The issue then is the ToDoRepository has a parameter, but is not supplied. And Unity is not fixing the issue by supplying it.

@Qamar appears to have a fix. You can also make sure the ToDoList dependency is resolved and pass to the resolved ToDoRepository in your code. It depends on how much you want to wire the plumbing and how much magic.

I like @Qamar's tip about Bootstrapper. Need to look into it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're getting at. I can only assume that I've missed something in my configuration of the project and/or Unity and that, subsequently, MVC is looking for a parameterless constructor for the Controller because it doesn't know how to cope with injecting the Repository.